# c# Изменить расширение файлов в папке

Tags: c#, winforms

В паке много файлов png и gif.
Как изменить у них расширение на jpg средствами и методами c#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string dir = @"C:\temp";
foreach(string fileName in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.png"))
{
  System.IO.File.Move(fileName, System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, ".jpg"));
}
```

Подождите, Вам и содержимое файлов надо переписать на jpeg?

```
string dir = @"C:\temp";
foreach(string fileName in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.png"))
{
  using (System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fileName))
  {
    img.Save(System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, ".jpg"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
  }
  System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Расширение (extension) в имени файла - это условность, служащая, в первую очередь, для удобства - сразу видно, какой тип данных файл содержит. В этом смысле, все файлы с изображениями могли бы иметь расширение ".картинка". "Но мы-то знаем", что типов картинок (даже растровых, не говоря уже о векторных) существует много. Внутренняя структура файлов с картинками разных форматов - разная. И правильно показать эти картинки сможет только программа, знающая об этих форматах и умеющая их читать и интерпретировать. А если мы подсунем такой программе файл с картинкой в формате, который ей неизвестен, правильно показать этот файл программа не сможет - как бы мы этот файл ни назвали.

Если Вы посмотрите на файлы с картинками разных форматов в (например) Notepad'е, то сможете заметить, что первые несколько байтов содержат указание на формат. Опираясь на этот маркер формата, та программа, которой Вы открываете Ваши картинки, знает что у них "внутре", как сказал бы профессор Выбегалло. И именно это является фактором, определяющим, как информация об изображении будет прочитана и показана.

Второй вариант кода, для каждого файла с расширением ".png", загружает изображение в объект `Image` и честно сохраняет это изображение в формате JPEG в новый файл с расширением ".jpg".

Comment: Как понять содержимое? Я вручную несколько штук просто переименовывал - все работает нормально. Картинки живые, или вы про что?

Comment: "Картинки живые" - это что? Был такой журнал - "Веселые Картинки". Вас код устраивает?

Comment: Изменение расширений не повлияло на работоспособность файлов. Размер не изменился тоже

Comment: Наверно устраивает. Сейчас буду пробовать

Comment: От того, что мы переименуем файл, то, что внутри файла, из PNG формата в JPEG не превратится.

Comment: А какой есть вариант чтобы изменилось. И как это проявляется? размер или что еще

Comment: @Андрей: Хм. Вы понимаете, что работа на изменение формата файла — достаточно большая: вам нужно распаковать исходные картинки в битмап, и запаковать их, при этом возможно с потерями? А переименование файла — задача на одну строку кода.

Comment: Сделал все по 1 варианту. Работает. Спасибо. Что такое второй вариант? Как еще появятся файлы попробую и другой метод, только поясните что это

Comment: @Андрей - см. добавление к ответу.

Comment: Прошелся опять первым методом по переименованию 25000 файлов. Все работает. Т.к из описание не понял что делает метод 2